# Core Graphics animation is not smooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, core-graphics, core-animation

So i am using Core Graphics to rotate a view

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
timer = 0.0f;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(callEverySecond) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)callEverySecond
{
if (timer>360) {
    timer=0.0f;
    [self rotateHand:timer];
}
else
{
    timer++;
    [self rotateHand:timer];
}
}

-(void)rotateHand:(CGFloat)angle
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.01 animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform matrix = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle*M_PI/180);
    [[self.rotate layer]setAffineTransform:matrix];
}];

[[self.rotate layer]needsDisplay];
}
```

Now the problem is that the rotation speed is non uniform and slows downs and speeds up randomly.

What is wrong here.

Comment: Use CoreAnimation, not UIView animation blocks. That's what's causing the problem.

Comment: Why do you need `timer > 360` check if you call `[self rotateHand]` anyway?

Comment: @random i derived this code from ios 7 in action so thought it shouldn't give a problem

Comment: @VitalyS. to change the angle provided

Comment: Your aim is just to animate something round in a circle? Do you need to be able to pause / stop it? Why is your timer running @ 0.01 seconds and calling a method called `callEverySecond`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timer with interval 0.01 wants to fire 100 times per second.  iOS only updates the screen 60 times per second.

Instead of using an `NSTimer` to “manually” perform animation, use a [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html).  A display link fires once per screen update (by default) and fires in sync with screen updates.

Also, the interval between screen updates is 1/60 = 0.01666667 seconds.  Therefore your `UIView` animation duration is less than the time between screen updates, so it can't produce any visible animation.  Get rid of your `UIView` animation.

If you just want to make a layer rotate continuously, you don't have to use an `NSTimer` or a `CADisplayLink`.  Instead, use a `CABasicAnimation` on the `transform.rotation` property:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
animation.duration = 3.6;
animation.fromValue = @0.0;
animation.toValue = @(2 * M_PI);
[self.rotate.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was following a book so i thought that it should be the correct way of doing rotation.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` is not meant to have very good precision. Besides, calling it 100 times/second is overkill for animation purposes. If you want a smooth rotation with a turn every second, use a repeating `CAAnimation` instead.